# Maven SFTP Repo Not Uploading

Tags: java, maven, sftp

I'm a bit of a noob with Maven and am trying to use SFTP to have a repo. This is my pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.wes</groupId>
    <artifactId>WorldLib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>buildstatic-repo</id>
            <name>BuildStatic Repository</name>
            <url>sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

I have also set up my settings.xml with the server credentials. My problem is that this is what I get when I execute `mvn deploy`:

```xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WorldLib 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/md-5/bungeecord-chat/1.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/md-5/bungeecord-parent/1.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (602 B at 12.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ WorldLib ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ WorldLib ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\Wesley Smith\Dropbox\Java\Dev\WorldLib\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ WorldLib ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Wesley Smith\Dropbox\Java\Dev\WorldLib\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WorldLib ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ WorldLib ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Wesley Smith\Dropbox\Java\Dev\WorldLib\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ WorldLib ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Wesley Smith\Dropbox\Java\Dev\WorldLib\target\WorldLib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ WorldLib ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Wesley Smith\Dropbox\Java\Dev\WorldLib\target\WorldLib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Wesley Smith\.m2\repository\me\wes\WorldLib\1.0-SNAPSHOT\WorldLib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Wesley Smith\Dropbox\Java\Dev\WorldLib\pom.xml to C:\Users\Wesley Smith\.m2\repository\me\wes\WorldLib\1.0-SNAPSHOT\WorldLib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ WorldLib ---
Downloading: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (758 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
Uploading: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/WorldLib-1.0-20160223.115637-9.jar
Uploaded: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/WorldLib-1.0-20160223.115637-9.jar (8 KB at 2.4 KB/sec)
Uploading: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/WorldLib-1.0-20160223.115637-9.pom
Uploaded: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/WorldLib-1.0-20160223.115637-9.pom (2 KB at 0.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/maven-metadata.xml (272 B at 0.3 KB/sec)
Uploading: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (758 B at 0.2 KB/sec)
Uploading: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/maven-metadata.xml (272 B at 0.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:04.923s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 23 06:56:49 EST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/283M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Seems like everything went well, eh? Actually, nope. Nothing is uploaded to the server but everything is in my local repo (as expected). Does anybody see what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you absolutely _sure_ that `sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/` is empty by connecting with the right credentials you supplied. Because *Uploaded: sftp://serv.buildstatic.net/maven-repo/me/wes/WorldLib/1.0-SNAPSHOT/WorldLib-1.0-20160223.115637-9.jar* doesn't really lie.

Comment: If you really need to work with sftp repos (which i don't recommend use repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva) than please upgrade the wagon provider to an uptodate version (2.10)....BTW: What is there a good reason to use sftp based repository? Apart from that your log output says there are artifacts uploaded...So may be i mistaken your question....

Comment: @Tunaki thanks for the info, I actually found that I was assuming the directory was in a different place. after a lot of searching, I found it.